# How to upgrade at once multiple releases with Helm for the same chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have multiple apps based on the same chart deployed with Helm. Let's imagine you deploy your app multiple times with different configurations:

```sh
helm install myapp-01 mycharts/myapp
helm install myapp-02 mycharts/myapp
helm install myapp-03 mycharts/myapp
```

And after I update the chart files, I want to update all the releases, or maybe a certain range of releases. I managed to create a PoC script like this:

```sh
helm list -f myapp -o json | jq -r '.[].name' | while read i; do helm upgrade ${i} mycharts/myapp; done
```

While this works I will need to do a lot of things to have full functionality and error control.
Is there any CLI tool or something I can use in a CI/CD environment to update a big number of releases (say hundreds of them)? I've been investigating Rancher and Autohelm, but I couldn't find such functionality.

Comment: With plain `kubectl` and perhaps `kustomize` this is much easier to do. All you do to deploy is `kubectl apply` and you can pass a directory as argument. See e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/

Comment: Could this be achieved by having an overlay folder for each app?

Comment: hundreds? You're well beyond needing a real deployment system. Have a look at argo, flux, jenkinsX, etc.

Comment: @jmservera yes, that is one way to solve it. Then one command to deploy them all `kubectl apply -k`

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, I could do it with kustomize and now it is easier to use and more flexible.  I'll take a look later to argo and flux to see if I can enhance rollbacks as well with some other tools. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip provided by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas) I've managed to create a simple structure to deploy and update lots of pods with the same image base.

I created a folder structure like this:

```
├── kustomization.yaml
├── base
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── namespace.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── one
    │   ├── deployment.yaml
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── two
        ├── deployment.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

So the main trick here is to have a `kustomization.yaml` file in the main folder that points to every app:

```yaml
resources:
- overlays/one
- overlays/two
namePrefix: winnp-
```

Then in the `base/kustomization.yaml` I point to the base files:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - service.yaml
  - deployment.yaml
  - namespace.yaml
```

And then in each app I use namespaces, sufixes and commonLabels for the deployments and services, and a patch to rename the base namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: ns-one
nameSuffix: "-one"

commonLabels:
  app: vbserver-one

bases:
- ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:

 - deployment.yaml

patches:
- target:
    version: v1 # apiVersion
    kind: Namespace
    name: base
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: ns-one
```

Now, with a simple command I can deploy or modify all the apps:

```bash
kubectl apply -k .
```

So to update the image I only have to change the `deployment.yaml` file with the new image and run the command again.

I uploaded a full example of what I did in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jmservera/legacyvb6ink8s/tree/main/aks/kustomize)